# Unable to predict with tf.keras sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction

I am a beginner in machine learning and have created a sequential model using tf keras. I am confused on how to use my_model to get a predictions based on one instance. The model uses 4 features columns and tries to determine the label "diff". I have posted the model code for context. The following code is from google machine learning crash course and my model is able to be compiled. I am confused on how to use the generated model to predict a value. My code for the prediction will be posted under the model code.

```
feature_columns = []

homePAG = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("homePAG")
feature_columns.append(homePAG)

awayPAG = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("awayPAG")
feature_columns.append(awayPAG)

homePPG = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("homePPG")
feature_columns.append(homePPG)

awayPPG = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("awayPPG")
feature_columns.append(awayPPG)

fp_feature_layer = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

def create_model(my_learning_rate, feature_layer):
  """Create and compile a simple linear regression model."""
  # Most simple tf.keras models are sequential.
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

  # Add the layer containing the feature columns to the model.
  model.add(feature_layer)

  # Add one linear layer to the model to yield a simple linear regressor.
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,)))

  # Construct the layers into a model that TensorFlow can execute.
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=my_learning_rate),
                loss="mean_squared_error",
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

  return model           


def train_model(model, dataset, epochs, batch_size, label_name):
  """Feed a dataset into the model in order to train it."""

  features = {name:np.array(value) for name, value in dataset.items()}
  label = np.array(features.pop(label_name))
  history = model.fit(x=features, y=label, batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs, shuffle=True)

  # The list of epochs is stored separately from the rest of history.
  epochs = history.epoch
  
  # Isolate the mean absolute error for each epoch.
  hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
  rmse = hist["root_mean_squared_error"]

  return epochs, rmse   


def plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, rmse):
  """Plot a curve of loss vs. epoch."""

  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel("Epoch")
  plt.ylabel("Root Mean Squared Error")

  plt.plot(epochs, rmse, label="Loss")
  plt.legend()
  plt.ylim([rmse.min()*0.94, rmse.max()* 1.05])
  plt.show()  

print("Defined the create_model, train_model, and plot_the_loss_curve functions.")

# The following variables are the hyperparameters.
learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 10
batch_size = 75
label_name = 'diff'

# Create and compile the model's topography.
my_model = create_model(learning_rate, fp_feature_layer)

# Train the model on the training set.
epochs, rmse = train_model(my_model, train_df, epochs, batch_size, label_name)

plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, rmse)

print("\n: Evaluate the new model against the test set:")
test_features = {name:np.array(value) for name, value in test_df.items()}
test_label = np.array(test_features.pop(label_name))
#test_label=tf.convert_to_tensor(test_label)
my_model.evaluate(x=test_features, y=test_label, batch_size=batch_size)
```

For this code I receive error :

```
x={'homePAG':np.int64(7), 'awayPAG':np.int64(7), 'homePPG':np.int64(7), 'awayPPG':np.int64(7)}
my_model.predict(x)
```

> ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class
> 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class
> 'numpy.int64'>"} values), <class 'NoneType'>

For this code I receive error :

```
z=np.array([[10,10,10,10]])
my_model.predict(z)
```

> ```
> ValueError: ('We expected a dictionary here. Instead we got: ', <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 4) dtype=int64>)
> ```